# How important is having an admin interface?

Tags: user-interface

So I'm working on a community website/forum in PHP and I'm thinking that depending on how popular it gets I should (eventually) have a few moderators, to do things like delete spam posts, ban users, ban by IP, etc.

This could be done by granting the moderators access to the database, but that's probably unsecure and downright wrong.

Should then I associate a *clearance* field to every user and then in the server, determining if the user has more than a given clearance, showing a "moderation tab" or section with all the options they should have or something like that?

I just want an idea of how this things work in a real life environment (I'm not talking about how Facebook or Twitter does this, but just how it works in a normal forum). Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's an invitation to discussion, and [StackOverflow is not a chat room or discussion board](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128550) - it can't be definitively answered ("an idea of how things work in a real life environment" is entirely too vague, and there are thousands of ways things can be done in "real life").

Comment: you should check at some popular forum software how they do it

Comment: @KenWhite isn't StackOverflow about overall development? After all [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is for purely programming related questions right?

Comment: @JohnDoe, StackOverflow is about programming (code and programmer's tools). [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is for overall development. You have them reversed. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary paradigm I've seen is having a `role` field for each user in the database and then having the `role` be things like `none`, `moderator` or `admin`. If it's `moderator` or `admin`, then unlock some of the protected functions they are allowed to run and give them access to management user interfaces.

For instance, you may have the function to `delete users` check if the [session](http://php.net/session_start) requesting use of the function is associated with a `user` that has a `moderator` or `admin` role or else disallow it. The key, I would say, is using sessions that require the `user` to login to create, using the user_id in the session to look up that `user` in the database, and then checking the `role` to see if they have permission before executing a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! that's what I was planning on doing exactly, it's the most logical way to do it I guess